# can app(target os below 4.3) run on ios6

Tags: iphone

Just wonder if the app(target os below 4.3) can run on ios6.
xcode 4.5 can not build the target below 4.3, does this mean ios6 does not accept app with os target below 4.3?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all apps built for older iOS versions will be able to run on future iOS versions.  However, you will have difficulty building older iOS apps to newer iOS devices.  Also, be careful when you release.  I had been working on one of my apps in iOS 4, and it was rejected for crashing.  I updated my xcode and realized some of the old code didn't work in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

an app targeted below 4.3 should be able to run on iOS6 devices as long as the app is built with an xcode less than 4.5. at least that was the case with an app I work on and it didn't seem to cause any problems (that i'm aware of). the difference is if you want to update that app using xcode 4.5 you'll have to change the target build to at least 4.3.

Comment: I believe it will not be possible to submit an app not supporting iOs 6 to AppStore, please correct me if I'm wrong. Together with the new Xcode limitations it forces us to drop the older iOs versions support.

Comment: you are likely right, i was referring to existing applications that are already published. They seem to be able to run on ios6. But if you want to specifically deploy to iO6 I think you need to build using a target of 4.3 or above. I haven't needed to submit any updates yet, or release a new app so I could be wrong.